# Changing values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this piece of code where I am trying to have a loop inside a loop to determine if a certain position is visted twice.

```
current_dir = 1
position = [0,0]
index = 0
move_list = ["L2", "L3", "L3", "L4", "R1", "R2", "L3", "R3", "R3", "L1", "L3", "R2", "R3", "L3", "R4", "R3", "R3", "L1", "L4", "R4", "L2", "R5", "R1", "L5", "R1", "R3", "L5", "R2", "L2", "R2", "R1", "L1", "L3", "L3", "R4", "R5", "R4", "L1", "L189", "L2", "R2", "L5", "R5", "R45", "L3", "R4", "R77", "L1", "R1", "R194", "R2", "L5", "L3", "L2", "L1", "R5", "L3", "L3", "L5", "L5", "L5", "R2", "L1", "L2", "L3", "R2", "R5", "R4", "L2", "R3", "R5", "L2", "L2", "R3", "L3", "L2", "L1", "L3", "R5", "R4", "R3", "R2", "L1", "R2", "L5", "R4", "L5", "L4", "R4", "L2", "R5", "L3", "L2", "R4", "L1", "L2", "R2", "R3", "L2", "L5", "R1", "R1", "R3", "R4", "R1", "R2", "R4", "R5", "L3", "L5", "L3", "L3", "R5", "R4", "R1", "L3", "R1", "L3", "R3", "R3", "R3", "L1", "R3", "R4", "L5", "L3", "L1", "L5", "L4", "R4", "R1", "L4", "R3", "R3", "R5", "R4", "R3", "R3", "L1", "L2", "R1", "L4", "L4", "L3", "L4", "L3", "L5", "R2", "R4", "L2"]
for i in move_list:
    turn = i[0]
    movement = int(i[1:])
    if turn == "R":
        current_dir += 1
        if current_dir > 4:
            current_dir = 1
    if turn == "L":
        current_dir -= 1
        if current_dir < 1:
            current_dir = 4
    if current_dir == 1: #Move North
        position[1] += movement
    if current_dir == 3: #Move South
        position[1] -= movement
    if current_dir == 2: #Move East
        position[0] += movement
    if current_dir == 4: #Move West
        position[0] -= movement
    position_2 = position
    current_dir2 = current_dir
    turn2 = turn
    for f in move_list[index+1:]:
        turn2 = f[0]
        movement2 = int(f[1:])
        if turn2 == "R":
            current_dir2 += 1
            if current_dir2 > 4:
                current_dir2 = 1
        if turn2 == "L":
            current_dir2 -= 1
            if current_dir2 < 1:
                current_dir2 = 4
        if current_dir2 == 1:  # Move North
            position_2[1] += movement2
        if current_dir2 == 3:  # Move South
            position_2[1] -= movement2
        if current_dir2 == 2:  # Move East
            position_2[0] += movement2
        if current_dir2 == 4:  # Move West
            position_2[0] -= movement2
        print position_2
    print position
    i = + 1
    index += 1
```

It should work fine but I have a problem where the value of position is changed when I am trying to change position_2 and I really don't understand why.

It changes at this part

```
if current_dir2 == 1:  # Move North
    position_2[1] += movement2
if current_dir2 == 3:  # Move South
    position_2[1] -= movement2
if current_dir2 == 2:  # Move East
    position_2[0] += movement2
if current_dir2 == 4:  # Move West
    position_2[0] -= movement2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is when you say `position_2 = position`. This makes position point at the same object as position_2. Helpful article [here](http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/). You should say:

```
position_2 = position[:]
```

to make them point at different objects.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out, The fact I am doing position2 = position means they are both pointing at the same arry. I learnt this before I just didn't realize it.

Comment: Also validate `i = + 1` part in your code. I believe its incorrect logic. `i` originally is a member of move_list but you are trying to add 1 to this.

Comment: @VijayakumarUdupa: It's not adding one, it's replacing it with 1. Doesn't hurt anything because `i` gets updated by the loop immediately, it's just a no-op for most purposes.